# input validation from model with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a function that validates input from database.
My question is how to validate the input if the current input is less than value in the database?

**the view**

```
<?php echo form_open('order/confirm');?>
    <div class="input-control text">
       <input type="text" name="paid_value" value="" placeholder=""/>
       <button class="btn-clear"></button>
    </div>
<?php echo form_close;?>
```

**the model**

```
function payment_validate(){
    $oid = $this->uri->segment(3);
    $paid = $this->input->post('paid_value');

    $this->db->select('*')
    ->from('order')
    ->join('payment','payment.order_id = order.order_id')
    ->where('order.order_id',$oid)
    ->where('order.total_bill >', $paid);

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $this->db->last_query(); //$query->result();
    }
    else{
    return array();
    }   
}
```

**the controller**

```
function confirm(){ // submit form payment
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in()){ 
    redirect('auth/login');
    }else{
        if($this->nekogear->payment_validate()){ // set error message
            $data['bill'] = $this->nekogear->payment_validate();

            echo "<pre>";
            die(print_r($data, TRUE));
        //$this->session->set_userdata('refered_from', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        //echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Insufficient fund.');
        //window.location='http://localhost/nekogear/index.php/cart/redirects'</script>";   
        }else{
        $data['goto'] = $this->nekogear->confirm_payment();

            echo "<pre>";
            die(print_r($data, TRUE));
        //echo "<script language='javascript'>alert('Accepted.');
        //window.location='http://localhost/nekogear'</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

if the inserted value is less than the current value, the print_r result is querying correctly
**less than current value**

```
    Array
(
    [bill] => SELECT *
FROM (`order`)
WHERE `order`.`order_id` =  '52F89602E6E'
AND `order`.`total_bill` > 10000
)
```

if
**more than current value**

```
Array
(
    [bill] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

so my guess something must be off in my if - else controller logic but I can't figure it out why its always skipping this if

```
if($this->nekogear->payment_validate()){
  // some error message here
}
```

any idea why? thanks.

---

**Solution**
I added form hidden for total bill into view then call it inside my controller.

```
$total = $this->input->post('total_bill');
$paid = $this->input->post('paid_value');
if($paid < $total){
// error message
}else{
// success message
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your model function:

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $this->db->last_query(); //$query->result();
    }
    else{
    return array(); <--- you are returning an empty array here.
    }
```

Also if you want to validate a form you can use form validation library from your controller. Speaking of your case you could use a callback function.

in your controller:

```
function confirm(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('paid_value', 'Paid value', 'required|callback_validate_payment');
     if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){ 
         // yes validation is true do something
        ......
      }
}
```

And specify your callback function in controller like:

```
public function validate_payment($str){ //$str holds the input post value
        //query here and check the value,return TRUE OR FALSE based on your condition. 
        // Also if you need you can set a custom error message here
 }
```

See more info [here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the idea, my current solution is to call the $total_bill into the submit form with hidden form then check whether the value is less than $total_bill value.